# SQL Help - How to "linearize" data?

Tags: sql, mysql, database, query-optimization

I'm not sure if "linearization" is the proper term, but I need a query that will output something like this:

```
item_name    item_price  first_name  last_name
-----------------------------------------------
'camera'    '100'        'Little'    'Timmy'
'computer'  '200'        'Little'    'Timmy'
```

Here's my DB: http://pastebin.com/iS4QKHEb

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: @OMG Ponies: thanks for improving the formatting of my question!

Comment: No Prob - force of habit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's:

```
SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN f.name = 'item_name' THEN fd.value ELSE NULL END) AS item_name,
       MAX(CASE WHEN f.name = 'item_price' THEN fd.value ELSE NULL END) AS item_price,
       MAX(CASE WHEN f.name = 'first_name' THEN fd.value ELSE NULL END) AS first_name,
       MAX(CASE WHEN f.name = 'last_name' THEN fd.value ELSE NULL END) AS last_name
  FROM FIELDDATA fd
  JOIN FIELD f ON f.id = fd.fieldid
```

But the problem is I don't see what there is to group by in order to get the two rows you want as output - the `datasourceid` is the same for all the records, so it can't be used.

And if you [likely] want this to be dynamic, it'll require [dynamic SQL via MySQL Prepared Statement syntax](http://rpbouman.blogspot.com/2005/11/mysql-5-prepared-statement-syntax-and.html).

Comment: the result of the SQL was just the first row of the results I needed. FieldData->FieldId = 100 and 101 are repeating (see Field->FieldSetId = 1 and FieldSet->Id = 1 and FieldSet->IsRepeating = 1). Does that help any? And yes, this needs to be dynamic since I don't know upfront 'item_name', 'item_price', etc. Is there a way to do this via one query (even if it is nested)?

Comment: I'm happy to build the SQL query in PHP -- as long as I have 1 final SQL to execute in the end.

Comment: @StackOverflowNewbie: That's fine, but the fundamental issue is the data issue I highlighted.

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain what you're looking for? An SQL query to just display all data? Something like

```
SELECT *
```

or

```
SELECT item_name, item_price, first_name, last_name
```

?

Comment: item_name, item_price, first_name, and last_name are not column names; they are column values. Additionally, item_name and item_price are repeating, while first_name and last_name are not.

The pastebin link I provided should help explain my headache.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately - if you've given us everything you have... "you can't get there from here".

If you want to get...

```
item_name    item_price  first_name  last_name
-----------------------------------------------
'camera'    '100'        'Little'    'Timmy'
'computer'  '200'        'Little'    'Timmy'
```

... from ...

```
INSERT INTO `fielddata` (`Id`, `DataSourceId`, `FieldId`, `Value`) VALUES
(1, 15, 100, 'camera'),
(2, 15, 101, '100'),
(3, 15, 100, 'computer'),
(4, 15, 101, '200'),
(5, 15, 102, 'Little'),
(6, 15, 103, 'Timmy');


INSERT INTO `field` (`Id`, `FieldAttributeId`, `FieldSetId`, `FormId`, `LookupFieldTypeId`, `Description`, `DisplayOrder`, `IsDeleted`, `Label`, `Name`) VALUES
(102, 0, 0, 1, 6, 'First Name Description', 0, 0, 'First Name Label', 'first_name'),
(103, 0, 0, 1, 6, 'Last Name Description', 0, 0, 'Last Name Label', 'last_name'),
(100, 0, 1, 1, 6, 'Item Name Description', 0, 0, 'Item Name Label', 'item_name'),
(101, 0, 1, 1, 6, 'Item Price Description', 0, 0, 'Item Price Label', 'item_price');
```

You'll need to be able to pull each column as a sub-select like so...

```
select fd.value, 
  from fielddata fd
 inner join field f on (fd.FieldId = f.Id)
 where f.name = 'item_name'
```

Problem is, once you get those put together, you don't have a column to "glue" the recordsets back  together - eg you won't know which price goes with which name because there's not a item_id of sorts on the fielddata table.

Let us know if there's something that accidentally got left out.

Just out of curiosity - is this class work?  Looks like an exercise of sorts...

Good luck!

Comment: no, this is not class work. It's for an actual application I am working on.

Can't Field->FieldSetId act as the "glue?"

Comment: Sorry - no offense intended with that class work question.  FieldSetId won't accomplish what we need.  We need a column in 'fielddata' that ties all attributes together to one "thing".  A column that says, this name and this price both belong to the same object (e.g. camera).